# i need to increment the id in the database in php automatically

Tags: php, html, increment

**Addcamera page code**

here i have 3 fields called name, sensor and orderid, here i need to fill all the fields. After filling i have saved these details database.

Once data added in database it will go to the cameralist.php file and display the names with edit and delete button.

My question is i want to order the databse by the order id in the cameralist.php page. consider first record name is sony and sensor name is sony and orderid becomes 1. now i want to insert new record name is canon and sensor is canon and id is 1. if i enter the same id, the id of sony should increment to 2   ,

Is this is possible or not, suggestion please

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     //echo json_encode($_POST);



    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
    {
        if($key!="submit"){

        $names[]=$key;
        $val[]= "'".$value."'";
        }
        //$names=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$value);
    }
    $output=implode(",",(array)($names));
    $v=implode(",",(array)($val));


$query="INSERT INTO `camera details` ($output)
                                        VALUES($v)";

$result=mysqli_query($db,$query) or die("OrderID Already Exists Add A new One");
    if($result)
    {

    header('location:cameralist.php');

    }
}
else {
?>



<div class="form">
<form method="POST" action="">
<?php

include('db.php');

$col="SHOW COLUMNS FROM `camera details`";
$output=mysqli_query($db,$col);

$kal=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($output))
{
    if($row['Field']!='id')
    {
        ?><div class="values"><?php echo $row['Field'];
        echo "<br>";?></div><br><br><?php
        array_push($kal, $row['Field']);
    }
}
?>
<div class="input">
<?php

foreach($kal as $key=>$value){
?>

<input type="text" name="<?php echo $value;?>" required /><br><br>
    <?php  } ?>




<br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">

<?php 

?>
<br>

</div>
<br><br>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

**cameralist.php file code**

```
<?php

include('db.php');
$sql="SHOW COLUMNS FROM `camera details`";
$n=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$kalai=array();

while($k=mysqli_fetch_array($n))
{
    if($k['Field']!='id')
    {
        array_push($kalai,$k['Field']);
    }
}

include('db.php');
$query="SELECT * FROM `camera details` ORDER BY OrderNo ";

$result=mysqli_query($db,$query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{?>
<tr><td><div class="values"><?php echo $row["$kalai[0]"]; ?></td></div>
<td><div class="edit"><a href="editcameradetails.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"] ?>">MODIFY</a></td></div>
<td><div class="delete"><a href="deletecameradetails.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"> DELETE</a></td></div></tr>
<br><br><br>
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: Is the `orderid`'s value from the user?

Comment: better way to set property of `id` column in SQL table AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: use `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the `id` field

Comment: Why do you include `db.php` multiple times?

Comment: @Swellar yes orderid is value from user

Comment: @Miggy already i have auto increment id in db

Comment: @Twinfriends thats not a problem

Comment: I'm curious, why let the user use the same `orderid`? Since the value is from the user, you can't use `AUTO_INCREMENT` in `orderid`

Comment: @kalaiselvan It may not be a problem, but its unnecessary. You waste time & ressources. Simply use `require_once('db.php');` at the beginning of the file and thats totally enough. No need to include is muliple times.

Comment: @Twinfriends thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @Swellar if i delete the id of particular details it will not exist in db . i want to display the names according to orderid...

Comment: Sticking with your idea, it is possible. Before inserting, check first if the `orderid` is already taken, if so, update that duplicate then increment its `orderid`. Then do the insert

Comment: @Swellar after the dublication how can i increment the orderid let me explain or edit the code what i have posted

Answer (score 0):

Simply use DESC so that new records appear in the top of the list you are displaying

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM `camera details` ORDER BY OrderNo DESC ";
```

by default its ASC

Comment: it's ok. if two row have the same id(1) i want to increment the another row to 2 how can i do this??/ suggestion

Comment: If you set the id to be auto incremented in your table definition, the DB system will prevent duplication and you dont have to worry about that because it will not happen.